# (Python) How do I remove all adjacent substrings in a string and keep only the first occurrence?

Tags: python, string

I've seen similar questions to this but unfortunately I couldn't find the exact case for my problem. What I was looking to do is remove all adjacent occurrences of a set substring but keep the first occurrence.

For example, given

```
s = "USER USER some words USER USER USER words"
substring = "USER"
```

The output I want would be

```
"USER some words USER words"
```

I've tried using sub(), split() but I couldn't find the answer I wanted. Would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `re`:

```py
import re

s = "USER USER some words USER USER USER words"
substring = "USER"

s = re.sub(fr"({re.escape(substring)})(\s+\1)+", substring, s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
USER some words USER words
```

Answer (score 1):

The old way would be to use a basic for loop:

```
string = "USER USER some words USER USER USER words"
substring = "USER"

newstring = []
s_old = ""
for s in string.split(" "):
    if (s!=s_old) or (s!=substring):
        newstring.append(s)
    s_old = s

print(" ".join(newstring))
```

Comment: This gets rid of any repetition.  Consider `string = "DAVE KNEW THAT THAT USER USER WAS DELETED"` gives the result `"DAVE KNEW THAT USER WAS DELETED"`. To fix change `if s!=s_old:` to `if s != s_old or s != substring:`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski oh youre right